# Get average value by date (with missing dates)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
Interest Rate ID    Interest Rate   Interest Rate Start Date
20                  3.5             2009-12-02 00:00:00.000
21                  3.75            2010-03-03 00:00:00.000
22                  4               2010-04-07 00:00:00.000
23                  4.25            2010-05-05 00:00:00.000
24                  4.5             2010-11-03 00:00:00.000
25                  4.25            2011-11-02 00:00:00.000
```

As you can see the `Interest Rate` spans from one month into the next. I need to work out the average interest for an entire month.

So lets say we pick `2010-11`. The interest rate for the `01/11/2010` to the `02/11/2010` was `4.25` as seen in row `23` but from `03/11/2010` onwards it was `4.5` percent. How can I write an SQL query (using TSQL) that uses the month and year to find the average interest rate?

Thanks

Comment: I think you should add some statistical knowledge for this scenario , then look for TSQL procedures .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pain, so I hope there is not an off-by-one error:

```
select sum(((case when end_date > lastdt then lastdt else end_date end) -
            (case when start_date < firstdt then firstdt else start_date end)
           )* t.rate) /
       sum((case when end_date > lastdt then lastdt else end_date end) -
           (case when start_date < firstdt then firstdt else start_date end)
          )
from (select t.*,
             (select top 1 start_date - 1 from t t2 where t2.start_date > t.start_date order by t2.start_date
             ) as end_date
      from t
     ) t cross join
     (select cast('2011-11-01' as date) as firstdt, cast(2011-11-30) as lastdt
where firstdt <= t.end_date and lastdt >= t.start_date
```

The idea is to calculate the number of days that each interest rate is valid.  The average is then the sum of the number of days times the rate divided by the number of days.

This is a bit complicated.  The inner query puts in an end date to each record.  The `where` clause just chooses the ones that overlap.  And the `select` has the calculations for the weighted average.

Comment: Some minor issues with the sytax but once fixed it works. Am yet to test it more thoroughly but I think it should be good to go. Thanks @Gordon.